# How can I find jpg. files from a list for a given folder and copy them to another folder location?

Tags: python, image, list, batch-file, jpeg

I am working in ecommerce and I need to find skus/image jpg files from a list of specific skus. I have a large folder housing about 5000+ jpg images and need to find all images for each list within the master list. I also need to COPY these images to another folder location of each list of image skus.

example.

the image file would be named **"800061_test.jpg"** and the list document which could be a txt., excel, or csv. would list out each jpg file as **"800061_test"**.

This list of matchning image skus has about 1500 skus of which there are varying amounts of duplicated needed for each image. So I may have 400 image skus that each need 2 duplicate images while I also may have 10, 30, 50, 100 image list skus that will need 10, 20, 30, or 40, image duplicates for each sku.

I've found separate bat. files that will duplicate images in a folder for me, however I have not been able to find a bat. file code that will FIND from a list within an image folder and copy those found images into another folder. SO i really need each list of image skus to have their own folders at the end of this thing. So it may be like 75 new folders.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

**I basically need to be able to copy images from a folder into another folder rather than manually finding and copy/pasting each of 400+ images per folder one by one. But I ALSO need to do this via an already compiled list of image skus. So I will have to do this about 75 times as I have a list of image skus with matching image jpgs.

**example: I have 400 separate product skus that all need to be duplicated 2x each for their matching image skus as: image_01.jpg, image_02.jpg. I have a previously used bat. file that will duplicate these by altering the "count=#". this gets me the "_02". But i need to do it in bulk and fins all of the 400 images in a folder that has about 8000 images in it. So each SKU whether it needs 2 dupes or 100 dupes needs to be able to be searched and found and copied to a folder.

Comment: I have only really been using bat. files for mass image renames within folders as well as  a duplicator code i found on Stackflow: setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=2
for %%F in (*.jpg) do (
  for /l %%i in (1, 1, %count%) do (
    set num=0%%i
    set num=!num:~-2!
    copy "%%F" "%%~nF_!num!%%~xF"
  )
)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using `glob` to retrieve all the `.dll` files from the Notepad++ folder. You can then grab just the filename off the full path.

```
import glob
glob.glob("D:\Program Files\Notepad++\*.dll")
```

Output

```
['D:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\iconv.dll',
 'D:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\libxml2.dll',
 'D:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\libxslt.dll',
 'D:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\NppShell_06.dll',
 'D:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\SciLexer.dll',
 'D:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\zlib1.dll']
```

Now with a list comprehension, we'll strip off the paths to just have the file names.

```
import os
[os.path.basename(i) for i in glob.glob("D:\Program Files\Notepad++\*.dll")]
```

Output

```
['iconv.dll',
 'libxml2.dll',
 'libxslt.dll',
 'NppShell_06.dll',
 'SciLexer.dll',
 'zlib1.dll']
```

Once you have a list of files, look at [shutil.copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) to copy them to some other folder.

Comment: Please forgive me, but I am not familiar with your above solution. I have only used bat. files for image renames for mass amounts of images within folders as well as a short image rename and _1, _2, _3 type rename code above for the other user who commented.